# Discover crashes every time on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, crash

I am using Kubuntu. Every time I open up Discover, it crashes right away. Rebooting doesn't work. The only situation it doesn't crash is when I disconnect my computer from internet. It works perfectly fine without internet.

Please help if you know the solution. Let me know what other information you need to diagnose the problem.

`sudo apt update` output"

```
> Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease            
> Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
> Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease    
> Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease     
> Hit:5 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease             
> Hit:6 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease    
> Get:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4,502 B]           
> Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease  
> Err:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease    The following
> signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client
> Repository <se-um@microsoft.com> Fetched 4,502 B in 2s (2,526 B/s)
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done All packages are up to date. W: An error
> occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not
> updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error:
> https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures
> were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository
> <se-um@microsoft.com> W: Failed to fetch
> https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  The following
> signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client
> Repository <se-um@microsoft.com> W: Some index files failed to
> download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`sudo apt upgrade` output:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following
> packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
> dconf-cli eqonomize-doc ipset khelpcenter4 kmymoney-common
> libalgorithm-c3-perl libalkimia5-7 libaqbanking-data libaqbanking35
> libaqbanking35-plugins libaqebics0   libaqhbci24 libaqofxconnect7
> libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcgi-fast-perl
> libcgi-pm-perl libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl  
> libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-inspector-perl
> libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-singleton-perl
> libcommon-sense-perl libdata-optlist-perl   libdatetime-locale-perl
> libdatetime-perl libdatetime-timezone-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl
> libdevel-caller-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl libdevel-stacktrace-perl  
> libdynaloader-functions-perl libeb16 libeval-closure-perl
> libexception-class-perl libfcgi-perl libfile-sharedir-perl
> libfinance-quote-perl libglade2-0 libgwengui-cpp0   libgwengui-qt5-0
> libgwenhywfar-data libgwenhywfar60 libhtml-tableextract-perl libipset3
> libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libkchart2 libkchart2-l10n
> libktoblzcheck1v5 libllvm9   libllvm9:i386
> libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl
> libmro-compat-perl libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl
> libnvidia-cfg1-435   libnvidia-cfg1-455 libnvidia-common-435
> libnvidia-common-455 libnvidia-compute-435 libnvidia-compute-435:i386
> libnvidia-compute-455 libnvidia-compute-455:i386  
> libnvidia-decode-435 libnvidia-decode-435:i386 libnvidia-decode-455
> libnvidia-decode-455:i386 libnvidia-encode-435
> libnvidia-encode-435:i386 libnvidia-encode-455  
> libnvidia-encode-455:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-435 libnvidia-fbc1-435:i386
> libnvidia-fbc1-455 libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 libnvidia-gl-435
> libnvidia-gl-435:i386 libnvidia-gl-455   libnvidia-gl-455:i386
> libnvidia-ifr1-435 libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-455
> libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl
> libpadwalker-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl
> libparams-validationcompiler-perl libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl
> libref-util-xs-perl librole-tiny-perl   libspecio-perl
> libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl
> libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-quote-perl libtidy5
> libtypes-serialiser-perl              libvariable-magic-perl
> linux-headers-5.4.0-65-generic linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-42
> linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-45 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-48         
> linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-65 linux-image-5.4.0-65-generic
> linux-modules-5.4.0-65-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-65-generic
> nvidia-compute-utils-435                      
> nvidia-compute-utils-455 nvidia-dkms-435 nvidia-dkms-455
> nvidia-kernel-common-435 nvidia-kernel-common-455
> nvidia-kernel-source-435 nvidia-kernel-source-455                  
> nvidia-utils-435 nvidia-utils-455 python-asn1crypto python-bs4
> python-cairo python-certifi python-cffi-backend python-chardet
> python-crypto python-cryptography                python-cssselect
> python-dateutil python-enum34 python-feedparser python-gdata
> python-glade2 python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-html5lib python-idna
> python-ipaddress          python-libxml2 python-lxml python-mechanize
> python-olefile python-openssl python-pil python-pkg-resources
> python-requests python-six python-urllib3 python-utidylib           
> python-webencodings python-weboob python-yaml
> xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455 xsltproc  
> Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.                             
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? Please edit your question with the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. It didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean *it didn't work*? You need to be more specific. Please post the full unredacted outputs of each command in the body of your question.

Comment: Okay. I have edited the description. You can check it out.

Comment: There's a lot of problems with your package management system.  The skype repo that you added is showing errors that it is invalid. The huge list of packages pending for autoremove is also a red flag.  Can you provide more context about what you've been up to when installing/maintaining software? What software have you added, changed, or removed since you last were able to perform updates successfully without errors -- and what exactly did you do?

Comment: I was just learning to use the system. Some basic stuff. Pretty much searching for guides online about how to install something, stc. The skype repo was probably added during that period of time. I didn't touch the "deep" stuff. What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall or server issue to me. The firewall is ufw. Try reading `man ufw`. You can also `tail -f /var/log/ufw.log` in terminal when you open /reproduce issue to see if it creates a new entry. If yes, then it is being blocked. Does this sound sensible to you @Nmath?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by installing KDE Plasma on Ubuntu

Comment: Problem solved. This problem might be a bug in 18.04 LTS. The system doesn't have native support for my laptop's wireless adapter. I upgraded the system to 21.04. It works like a charm